# Do not generate IEEE references

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm trying to generate IEEE type references. Could you please advice me why I don't see references in my PDF file.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{testing.bib}
@article{doran2014detection,
title="{Detection, Classification, and Workload Analysis of Web Robots}",
author="Doran, Derek",
year="2014"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{IEEE article}
\author{Nilani A}

\begin{document}\maketitle
\lipsum[1]See \cite{doran2014detection} for more info 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{testing}
\end{document}
```

Following is my PDF File

[image]

Comment: you not have bibliography in your document example. without it you will not have references.

Comment: You should do: pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex. First pdflatex writes references in aux file. bibtex processes them. second pdflatex inserts bibliography in your document and fourth solves `?`.

Comment: @Ignasi - The OP's issue was a lack of proper capitalization of the argument of `\bibliographystyle`.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
```

is faulty. It should be

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

Here's an MWE (mininum working example):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testing.bib}
@misc{doran2014detection,
  title  = "Detection, Classification, and Workload 
            Analysis of Web Robots",
  author = "Doran, Derek",
  year   = "2014",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % <-- not "ieeetran"

\title{IEEE article}
\author{Nilani A}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
See \cite{doran2014detection} for more info.
\bibliography{testing}
\end{document}
```